# How to suppress url encoding with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, encoding, spring-boot

I have created a GET/POST API using Spring boot which has a http url parameter say refid. Now this parameter is already encoded before invoking GET/POST request 
e.g. http://localhost:8080/users/TESTFNkJXiQAH%2FJBKxigBx

But, when I deploy this through Spring Boot, the encoded refid is encoded again and the refid changes. i.e. it becomes:

http://localhost:8080/users/TESTFNkJXiQAH%252FJBKxigBx

I want to suppress this 2nd encoding by Spring boot. Can anyone advise here?

Comment: How do you produce this url?

Comment: refid is encrypted form of few parameters, which is then encoded and we then append it to URL and invoke a GET or POST with that.

Comment: Why not use URL.decode on this parameter?

Comment: So I decoded it before calling find: `refId = URLDecoder.decode(RefId, "UTF-8");
        List<TestObject> objList = TestObjectDao.findByrefId(
                refId);`
Still the url comes as double encoded i.e. same as previous case.

Comment: I'll post my code as an answer, as comments don't format code properly.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if you are still having this problem or you found out why it's happening, but because I was trying to explain to someone the phenomenon, I looked if there is already a good explanation. But since you also ask and I didn't find any, here is my answer.

So you encode your refid

> TESTFNkJXiQAH%2FJBKxigBx

before you send it through the url, which then you give into a browser. Now this is only the encoded refid. When you call it through a URL directly you have to encode it again, according to the HTML URL encoding standards. That’s why the double escape. Also read [this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=61269). E.g. so if your refid looks like this

> test%123

and you encode it you turn it into

> test%25123

now if you also want to pass it through a url on the browser you'd have to encode it again.

> test%2525123

But if a service A is using this service and service A encodes this refid properly then you wont have this problem. It's happening only because you are trying to call this api endpoint through the browser.

Of course I take for granted that you are doing this:

```
String decoded = URLDecoder.decode(refid, "UTF-8");
```

in your controller

Comment: @SimonLogic then it's better you pass your parameter as POST request then you don't need to encode at all

Comment: Path params are vital for REST methods. I found some question here, but there is no proper answer. I think I need to use AOP to manually decode params annotated by @PathVariable for String type.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the decoded URL in first place instead of doing inconvenient things to stop double encoding.
You get already decoded field in rest controller.
Example if you pass www.xyz.com?name=nilesh%20salpe

you will get value of param name as "nilesh salpe" and not "nilesh%20salpe"

Comment: dont work if decoded url has slash / in the encoded param

Answer (score -2):

This is a basic example of URLDecoder:

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/users/{refId}", method = GET)
   public void yourMethod(@PathVariable("refId") String refId) {
      // This is what you get in Spring Boot
      String encoded = refId; //"TESTFNkJXiQAH%252FJBKxigBx"

      String decoded = URLDecoder.decode(encoded, "UTF-8");

      System.out.println(decoded);

      // Result TESTFNkJXiQAH%2FJBKxigBx
   }
```

Comment: I dont know my response went above. Please check the above comment.

Comment: One more problem I see is that I could not find the encoded refid in my application debug but, the URL shows % as %25. The code where I am trying to decode is on the original refid which I passed.

Comment: How to get the refid from URL?